# Set cookies with Javascript to remember show state by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

Please, advice. I want to set cookies to my working simple javascript code. The div is showed by clicking on the link, but if the page reloads the div will hide. I need to set cookies to remember the show state for 7 days for e.g.

Javascript

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('auth_block').style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv()">
      <img src="/images/cont_btn.png">
    </a>

<div style="display:none;" id="auth_block">Some information</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use **[$.cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)**:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if($.cookie('display') != null) {
        $('#auth_block').show();
    } else {
        $.cookie('display', $('#auth_block').css('display'), { expires: 7 });
        $('#auth_block').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work for me, only shows div block but hides it after window reloads.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery cookie plugin?

Comment: Yeah and other scripts work fine with cookie plugin. Perhaps I should add/change smth in html code?

Comment: You don't need the `onclick` inside your HTML anymore. Also, did you receive any error in the brwoser console?

Comment: It's happen at different part of your code. Please check again

Comment: I've looked for cookie "display" in browser and it's there. So as I understand the cookie is set up but maybe some problem with script.