# Remember JavaScript with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I’m working on a left menu bar that expands on a button click.

I want to save the state of the menu, if it is expanded or not.
When it refreshes the class must still be added.

```
$('#menu-action').click(function() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  $('.main').toggleClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-close');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-bars');
  } else {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-bars');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-close');
  }
});

// Add hover feedback on menu
$('#menu-action').hover(function() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("active")) {
        $('.sidebar').addClass("active")
    }
});

$(window).unload(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("active", $('.sidebar').hasClass("active"));
});
```

Local storage is not supported by all browsers. See the link above. You can use extensions like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) to support old browsers.

Another option is to use cookie plugin as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22495052/6033819).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not yet made it clear on how you want to read or write cookies, I'd recommend using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to make handling a little easier. Handling cookies with plain JS is possible, but a rather cumbersome task.

A solution using the mentioned library would work like this (Expecting you have added `js.cookie.js` before your code to your HTML)

```
// Store references to reusable selectors
var $menuAction = $('#menu-action');
var $menuActionI = $menuAction.find('i'); // the <i> inside #menu-action
var $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var activeClass = 'active';

// Docs: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.1.0#basic-usage
var isActive = Cookies.get('site-menu-active') || false;

function toggleMenu() {
    $sidebar.toggleClass('active', isActive);
    $('.main').toggleClass('active', isActive);
    $menuAction.toggleClass('active', isActive);
    $menuActionI.toggleClass('fa-close', isActive);
    $menuActionI.toggleClass('fa-bars', isActive);

    isActive = !isActive;
    Cookies.set('site-menu-active', isActive, { expires: 7 });
 }

// Calling immediately to set to state read from cookie
toggleMenu();

// Add click interaction
$menuAction.click(toggleMenu);

// Add hover feedback on menu
$menuAction.hover(function() {
    $sidebar.toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The Html5 storage is the best option for these scenario. Here you can change the localStorage to sessionStorage based on the requirement:
1)localStorage - even close the browser the data is alive
2)sessionStorage - while close the browser the data is removed
We can also remove the stored data

$('#menu-action').click(function() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  $('.main').toggleClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  localStorage.setItem("active", $('.sidebar').hasClass('active'));

  if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-close');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-bars');
  } else {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-bars');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-close');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("active")){
      $('.sidebar').addClass('active');
      $('.main').addClass('active');
      $('#menu-action').find('i').addClass('fa-close');
      $('#menu-action').find('i').removeClass('fa-bars');
  }
});
```